# Why is numpy.save not saving the file on linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to save a Numpy array in my system using numpy.save. The code is working fine without an error on windows but on linux, the code is working fine but it is not saving the numpy array to the desired location. works fine in windows but on linux i can't see the file

On windows:

```
import numpy as np
dataset = np.arange(100)
np.save("C:\\Users\\Bhushan\\Documents\\Test.npy",dataset)
#working fine with file saved at the location
```

On linux:

```
import numpy as np
dataset = np.arange(100)
np.save("Test.npy",dataset)
# It should save next to the program file but i couldn't see any numpy array file
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Check the directory where you are currently working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try

```
np.load("Test.npy")
```

you can see if it has actually saved it and you're looking in the wrong place

```
import os
os.path.abspath(".")
```

to see where you are (and where the file will be saved)